# What's a better way to call a JavaScript function in another file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm doing a job of front-end at the time, and for this I am having to call various functions javascript / jQuery in other files. So, I'm using PHP with CodeIgniter and I trying to make a call from a PHP function call another function javascrip.Follow what I'm trying to do:

PHP:

```
public function validaInclusao() {

        getAtributoJanelaPai("slCusto");
    }

function getAtributoJanelaPai($idCampo) {

    carregaScriptsJquery();

    echo "getAtributoJanelaPai('$idCampo');";
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function getAtributoJanelaPai(idCampo) {
    alert('getAtributoJanelaPai');
    var element = window.opener.document.getElementById(idCampo);
    var value = '';

    if (element.tagName === 'SELECT') {
        value = element.selectedIndex + '|' + element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    } else if (element.tagName === 'INPUT') {
        value = element.value;
    }

    alert(value);
}
```

So, as it would be in line:

```
echo "getAtributoJanelaPai('$idCampo');";
```

Comment: PHP can't call javascript functions. PHP is server-side and javascript is client-side.

Comment: My question is : what is calling the PHP function? An AJAX call? If yes, you can handle that in the success callback of the AJAX request. If not, the call is not dynamic, so render the page already modified.

Comment: No, I'm don't using ajax request for that function. But is the php function calling javascript function, and not otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create javascript file that will return some thing

```
function getAtributoJanelaPai(idCampo) {
alert('getAtributoJanelaPai');
var element = window.opener.document.getElementById(idCampo);
var value = '';

if (element.tagName === 'SELECT') {
    value = element.selectedIndex + '|' + element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
} else if (element.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    value = element.value;
}

return(value);
}
```

and in php file use this, include created js file first.

```
public function validaInclusao() {

    getAtributoJanelaPai("slCusto");
}

function getAtributoJanelaPai($idCampo) {

carregaScriptsJquery();

echo "<script language=javascript>document.write(getAtributoJanelaPai(idCampo));</script>";
}
```

or try this one

```
echo "<script language=javascript>getAtributoJanelaPai(idCampo);</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you have to import the Javascript file into your document.

In your head section put the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScripts.js"></script>
```

Where "myScripts.js" is the filename of the Javascript file.

And this is how you do the echo:

```
<?php echo getAtributoJanelaPai($idCampo); ?>
```

Comment: The echo would have to be within `<script>` tags below the `myScripts.js` import, not an echo in the `myScripts.js` file

Comment: The one thing who is impress is: "getAtributoJanelaPai('slCusto');"